# How to add elements to a column if there is a condition in flutter?

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart

I have this code:

```
Column(
        children: [
            MyFirstWidget(),
            MySecondWidget(),
        ],
);
```

Now I want to add some widgets to that column if there is a condition. Here an example:

```
Column(
        children: [
            MyFirstWidget(),
            MySecondWidget(),
            if(condition == true) {
               MyThirdWidget(),
               MyFourthWidget(),
            }
        ],
);
```

I know this code is wrong, but how can I do this is correct dart programming?

Comment: Hello! what kind of condition do you wanted to applying on widgets.Kindly expain in details so someone will help.

Comment: The condition doesn't matter, in this case is (vehicle.isConvertible == true)

Comment: Have you tried my answer? I also address that you don't need to do ` == true`.

Comment: It was just what I needed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Dart 2.3, they added the collection `if` and spread operators which you can use here to conditionally add these widgets.

The collection `if` conditionally adds the list of third and fourth widgets and the spread operator concisely inserts these elements into the collection.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    MyFirstWidget(),
    MySecondWidget(),
    if(condition == true)
      ...[MyThirdWidget(), MyFourthWidget()]
  ],
);
```

Additionally doing `== true` is unnecessary. You can just do `if(condition)` for slightly cleaner code:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    MyFirstWidget(),
    MySecondWidget(),
    if(condition)
      ...[MyThirdWidget(), MyFourthWidget()]
  ],
);
```

These both will only show the third and fourth widgets when condition is `true`.